# iOS: Creating many IBOutlets has performance overhead?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, storyboard

If we create many IBOutlets from the storyboard/xib to the ViewController/View then will it cause performance overhead? If so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the `IBOutlet` Definition in Apple Developer.

Here's [Outlets documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html)

We can see this

```
the more outlets an object has, the more memory it takes up. 
If there are other ways to obtain a reference to an object, 
such as finding it through its index position in a matrix, 
or through its inclusion as a function parameter, 
or through use of a tag (an assigned numeric identifier), 
you should do that instead.
```

So it will cause performance overhead.

For more details, you can see the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's why you should create many storyboards base on your purposes. 
For example : Setting Storyboard, Main Storyboard, User Storyboard, Picker Storyboard.